# Converting a bitset to signed

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I have a std::bitset<32> and I want to isolate the right 16 bits and output those bits as if they were a signed number.  I also am going to want to output the entire 32 bit thing as a signed number down the road.  However, Bitset does not support a signed int to_string().

for example
1010000000100001 1111111111111111:

I want one output to be:

-1608384513 for the whole sequence

-1 for the right 16 bits.

Any slick ways of converting them?

Comment: You could possibly try this (but I'd like validation first from more experenced C++ bitset users): `unsigned long long val = bitset.to_ullong(); int16_t final = (int16_t) (val & 000000000000FFFF);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a 16-bit number you can use `to_ulong()`, drop the upper 16 bits, and reinterpret as `int16_t`.

Similarly, for a signed 32-bit number you can call `to_ulong()`, and reinterpret as a signed `int32_t`.

```
std::bitset<32> b("10100000001000011111111111111111");
int16_t x16 = (int16_t)(b.to_ulong() & 0xFFFF);
int32_t x32 = (int32_t)b.to_ulong();
cout << x16 << endl;
cout << x32 << endl;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/UKAWAe)

Comment: Do you even need the bit mask?  The cast chops the high bits off anyway, so it shouldn't really matter what their value is.